# how to generate const array by macro in Rust?

Tags: rust, rust-macros

I want to generate this const array:

```
const EXPS: [i64; 9] = [1,
    10_i64.pow(1), 10_i64.pow(2), 10_i64.pow(3), 10_i64.pow(4),
    10_i64.pow(5), 10_i64.pow(6), 10_i64.pow(7), 10_i64.pow(8)]
```

by macro:

```
define_exps!(9);
```

where the argument `9` specifies the length of array.

Can I make this by macro?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You can do that as a procedural macro, but also as a declarative macro using [dtolnay's `seq-macro`](https://github.com/dtolnay/seq-macro):

```rust
macro_rules! define_exps {
    ( $num:literal ) => {
        const EXPS: [i64; $num] = ::seq_macro::seq!(N in 0..$num {
            [
                #(
                    10_i64.pow(N),
                )*
            ]
        });
    };
}
```

Comment: How come `EXPS` can be used outside of `define_exps!`? Doesn't this break macro hygiene?

Comment: @jthulhu Hygiene only applies to local variables, not to items.

Comment: @jthulhu You might be thinking of declarative macros 2.0 (i.e. `feature(decl_macro)`), in which `EXPS` would *not* be accessible from the outside (due to hygiene).